# How to add class to the body tag

Tags: jquery, addclass

Im not to much of a newbie to jQuery but i think im having a total blonde day as I cant get this to work.

Ive built a wordpress website and I have a calendar plugin that adds a class to the body. I have a lot of styling i need to apply to the body tag by adding a class to it.

This code just simp0ly isnt working. Any help would be great thanks.

```
if ( jQuery("body").hasClass("tribe-is-responsive") ) { 
    jQuery("body").addClass("nbe-section-page");
}
```

Comment: if what? there is no condition, so it NEVER will be true. There are so much syntx errors. did you test that code?? sry bad formatting of code

Comment: if the script is in head tag, you should wrap the script in dom ready.

Comment: @pc-shooter condition is there.

Comment: @pc-shooter there is a condition `if ( 
jQuery("body").hasClass("tribe-is-responsive") )`

Comment: Sry man!! the formatting is quite strange, thats why

Comment: is it wrapped in a $(document).ready(); function?

Comment: If you run it without the condtition, it works?, also please post the html part

Comment: it can be simplified as `jQuery("body.tribe-is-responsive").addClass("nbe-section-page");` - not a solution to your problem though

Comment: let us show the complete javascript

Comment: Check body tag in ``firebug``. Syntax is true. ``$(document).ready(function(){if ( jQuery("body").hasClass("tribe-is-responsive") ) { 
    jQuery("body").addClass("nbe-section-page");
}});``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("body").hasClass("tribe-is-responsive")) { 
         $("body").addClass("nbe-section-page");
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just an update as this snippet adds the nbe-section-page class to all elements on the page that also share the tribe-is-responsive class. Is there any way that I can apply this only to the body tag?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to eeK and Arun P Johny.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("body.tribe-is-responsive").addClass("nbe-section-page");
});
```

I guess im kind of used to write conditional php.

Thanks for your help guys.